# Automate creating infrastructure in AWS using Terraform through jenkins Job

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-plugins, terraform

I'm trying to automate creating infrastructure in AWS using Terraform through jenkins Job.

Below are the steps

1.I have installed Jenkins on AWS Linux EC2 instance

2. I have installed terraform plugin in jenkins as shown below under
   Manage jenkis/Manage Plugins
   [image]
   and under Manage jenkis/Global Tool COnfiguration made the below change
   [image]
   3.create  a new jenkins job with the below configuration
   [image]
   4.I'm getting the below errors while running  the job
   [image]
   [image]

Appreciate your help to find the fix

Added the aws version as suggested in the below comments and below is the console output from jenkins

[image]

Comment: It looks like Terraform is failing because `terraform init` hasn't been run. I've not used the [Jenkins Terraform plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/terraform) before so can't be sure but it hasn't had any updates in over a year which predates the requirement for having to init a location before running any other Terraform actions against it. If so it might now be usable as is and you'll have to fall back to using a shell script build step.

Answer (score 2):

You need define the release version for terraform provider `aws`, example:

```
provider "aws" {
  version = "~> 1.0"
  ..
}
```

Reference:

[Provider Versions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html#provider-versions)

Comment: Job is still failing after adding the version ( version = "~> 1.5").This is what i see the change in log file is  "version requirements: "~> 1.5""   everything remains same in the log file

Comment: Did you run `terraform init` before `terraform plan/apply`?

Comment: Yes,I did ran terraform init

Comment: Could you update with the errors in your post after made above changes?

Comment: Started by user admin
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TerraformTest
[terraform-plugin] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/org.jenkinsci.plugins.terraform.TerraformInstallation/Linux_terrafrom/terraform get -update
[terraform-plugin] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/org.jenkinsci.plugins.terraform.TerraformInstallation/Linux_terrafrom/terraform apply -input=false -state=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TerraformTest/terraform-plugin/terraform-plugin.tfstate
[0m[1m[33mPlugin reinitialization required. Please run "terraform init".[0m
[33mReason: Could not satisfy plugin requirements.

Comment: Plugins are external binaries that Terraform uses to access and manipulate
resources. The configuration provided requires plugins which can't be located,
don't satisfy the version constraints, or are otherwise incompatible.

[0m[31m1 error(s) occurred:

* provider.aws: no suitable version installed
  version requirements: "~> 1.5"
  versions installed: none

Comment: [0m[33mTerraform automatically discovers provider requirements from your
configuration, including providers used in child modules. To see the
requirements and constraints from each module, run "terraform providers".
[0m
[31m
[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1merror satisfying plugin requirements[0m

[0m[0m[0m

Comment: FATAL: java.lang.Exception: Terraform Apply failed: 1
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.terraform.TerraformBuildWrapper.executeApply(TerraformBuildWrapper.java:249)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.terraform.TerraformBuildWrapper.setUp(TerraformBuildWrapper.java:269)
 at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:157)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
 at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1727)
 at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
 at

Comment: hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)

Finished: FAILURE

Comment: You should edit that error message into your question where it can actually be read rather than dump it into comments

Comment: I have added the console output after making the changes to this question @BMW